# Bootstrap column grid: Margin issues

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-grid

While splitting my `page.aspx` in 4 `columns`, I notice in the `first` and `fourth` `columns` several `blank` spaces (on the `left` and `right` side, respectively), thus narrowing the `width` of the `second` and `third` columns.

Knowing a way to get rid of such default `margin` issues within the `first` and `fourth` `columns` so as to get **proper** equally-balanced columns over the whole `page.aspx` would highly be appreciated.

To better illustrate such issue, I've written the following code:

```html
<link rel=stylesheet href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="...">
    </div>
    <div class="img">
      <img src="...">
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3" style="font-size:16px">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 border-left">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 border-left">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 border-left">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That code doesn't demonstrate the problem.

Comment: See [container-fluid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/overview/#fluid)

Comment: @Quentin: probably it does not.., but empirically running it illustrates the unexpected and observed margin issues for which i am attempting to get the rationale. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because of the container you're using, the one you want is `container-fluid` which has no margin no padding, no nothing haha.

`container` gives each div a specified fixed width, that is the reason behind the blank spaces

You can check the documentation here: [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/overview/#fluid)

Comment: Thanks a lot h0merr, I do appreciate the explanations. Cheers.